# How does this polyfill work for document.queryselectorall?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand this polyfill for queryselectorall? Specifially this line:

```
styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}";
```

https://gist.github.com/connrs/2724353

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
    document.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
        var doc = document,
            head = doc.documentElement.firstChild,
            styleTag = doc.createElement('STYLE');
        head.appendChild(styleTag);
        doc.__qsaels = [];

        styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}";
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);

        return doc.__qsaels;
    }
}
```

Comment: this line is css-expression that fill array `doc.__qsaels`

Answer (score 1):

It is abusing the [`expression` "feature"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634.aspx) of CSS. When computing the style of the `x` property (which happens on the reflow triggered by `scrollBy(0, 0)`), Internet Explorer will execute this snippet for all elements that match the selector.

[CSS expressions are officially despised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx) since IE 8…