# What does {x:expression(...)} do?

Tags: javascript, expression

I came across this polyfill of `querySelectorAll` for IE7:

https://gist.github.com/connrs/2724353

I had thought that I am Okayish in JavaScript, but I have never seen anything like the quoted part in line 9 of the polyfill:

```
{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}
```

Apparently, it is a JavaScript object with key `x` and value `expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))`, but other than this much I know, it is mysterious to me. What does this `expression` function do? I was not able to find anything close via google.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the value for `x` is not expression function but its result.

Comment: I know that code is being appended to a stylesheet. Not sure why though.

Comment: @MikeC: yes, I get that.

Comment: This similar question provides pointers to CSS expressions, and references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594395/how-does-this-polyfill-work-for-document-queryselectorall

Comment: Thanks for digging that out. Somebody has stumbled upon it before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking at a generated CSS rule. This is not a JavaScript object, but a CSS declaration block.

The line

```
styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}";
```

concatenates a CSS selector with a declaration block into a string of CSS. The declaration block contains a dummy CSS property called `x` with a value of `expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))`.

What `expression()` *is*, is a non-standard feature of old versions of IE that allows the author to execute arbitrary JavaScript directly and obtain a value for use within CSS. So while the entire string is a CSS declaration block, `document.__qsaels.push(this)` is in fact a JavaScript expression.

What this expression does, is push any element matching the CSS selector into the `__qsaels` array so that the polyfill can return it as the set of elements matched by the selector.<sup>1</sup> This, in essence, is how the polyfill works.

As a concrete example, calling the polyfilled `document.querySelectorAll(".foo")` causes IE7 to append the following CSS to the document stylesheet:

```
.foo{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}
```

With some indentation and newlines so it resembles conventional CSS:

```
.foo {
  x: expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))
}
```

Here you can see that this CSS rule will apply to any element that matches `.foo`, causing each element to be added to `__qsaels` before it is returned.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For whatever reason, IE seems happy to execute `expression()` statements even on unknown properties (AFAIK there isn't such a property called `x` even on IE7, but what do I know?).</sub>

Comment: That's a rather genius polyfill.

Comment: Mike C, but it does not work like ptdixon mentions over there.

Comment: @Stack0verflow It does in quirks mode. So it's not a perfect solution but I had no idea you could even do this in old IE.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thank you very much. Now that I learned it is actually css expression, not JavaScript, I was able to dig out something. Still researching.