# document.querySelectorAll polyfill

Tags: javascript, dom, polyfills, selectors-api

I was asked in a telephonic interview to write a `document.querySelector`/ `document.querySelectorAll` polyfill, utilizing the following

- `document.getElementById`
- `document.getElementsByClassName`
- `document.getElementsByTagName`

The polyfill should be able to take any combination of css selectors, for example `.foo p.bar.baz span.qax`.

I could not come up with a proper solution.

---

### My approach ...

... was to parse the `selector` and start for the right.

With respect to `.foo p.bar.baz span.qax`

- I wanted to parse the selector in something like `['.foo', ['p', '.bar', 
  '.baz'], ['span', '.qax']`
- take the right most element,

  - if it is an array, for the right most element of the array, fetch nodes with the available methods.
  - otherwise for the right most element of the array, fetch nodes with the available methods
- and filter the available node with respect to the remaining selectors in the left

---

### Where did I fail?

- I could not figure out the regex to parse the selector

---

I guess I should have started from the left instead of right of the parsed selectors.

---

I searched for [document.queryselector polyfill](https://www.google.com/search?q=document.queryselector%20polyfill&rct=j) but could not comprehend `{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}` in most of the available solutions.

---

Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks!

---

**Updates w.r.t. comments**

Thanks everyone for your suggestions/comments.

@Sitian Liu, my primary query is 'how to implement `querySelectorAll` with strictly `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.getElementsByTagName`' I thought I could club `{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}` Thanks @RobG for the pointer to [What does {x:expression(...)} do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302220/what-does-xexpression-do).

@SravanS, I sorry, I don't know what is your definition of `heavy`, but the selector that was given to me had `classes`, `tags`, and `child selector`.

> Polyfill intentionally omits attribute selectors

@guest271314 I don't remember if attribute selector was present. I guess it was intentionally omitted

@SravanS I appreciate your comments, but I am afraid to state, that you are assuming too much. Interviewer did  want to dry run the code with respect to an HTML markup.

@SravanS @jfriend00 I am aware of [sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js), I thought I could get easy to comprehend answer here in StackOverflow, than reading through a 2242 lines of code. :)

@RobG echoed my concerns.

---

After going through all the comments, I am wondering if this question should be part of an 30 mins telephonic interview process, that too when you have to code it live in a Google Doc.

Comment: Hey are you asking what `document.__qsaels.push(this)` is about or how to implement `querySelectorAll` with strictly `document.getElementById`
`document.getElementsByClassName`
`document.getElementsByTagName`. These are two very different questions

Comment: I think, you shouldn't try to parse all data at once and I think, they didn't want you to parse heavy CSS selectors such as `p.class1 #op ~ .class2`

Comment: _"I was asked in a telephonic interview to write a document.querySelector/ document.querySelectorAll polyfill, utilizing the following

document.getElementById
document.getElementsByClassName
document.getElementsByTagName"_ Polyfill intentionally omits attribute selectors?

Comment: In general, my approach would be to first split the whole selector by spaces, then you get an array
Then take each element in this array and split them by `#` and `.`, which gives you a data structure as you wants.

Comment: @SravanS _"In general, my approach would be to first split the whole selector by spaces"_ For selector `#abc>.123` ?

Comment: As per an interview point of view, I don't think they wanted to create a full fledged selector polyfill. The scope of the question would most probably fall under element, id, class and child selectors.

Anyways, reading jQuery source would be of great help

Comment: @SravanS - jQuery uses the [Sizzle selector engine](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/tree/master) to backfill when `querySelectorAll()` is not supported (only old browsers now are missing that).  jQuery also has it's own additions to the selector syntax (beyond what `querySelectorAll()` supports that it has to check for.

Comment: I think you're looking for [*What does {x:expression(…)} do?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302220/what-does-xexpression-do).

Comment: @SravanS—reading the jQuery source is a waste of time. The Sizzle selector engine linked by jfriend00 might help but 1,500 or so lines of code is a lot to wade through.

Comment: Hello @all, thank you very much for your comments, I have updated the OP, w.r.t. the comments. Thanks!

Comment: If somebody could implement this properly during telephonic interview he would be genius or copy pasting existing solution. I can image basic algorithm, which will handle selectors like `.classname`, `tagname` and `#id` without any combinations. I am expecting that they wanted simple switch with 3 regular expressions for 3 variants and it is all.

Comment: _I am wondering if this question should be part of an 30 mins telephonic interview process_ – At Facebook, they have 2 questions like this to be solved in 35 mins, plus 10 mins of chit chat not related to interview - a total of 45 mins telephonic ☺️

Answer (score 0):

> **Where did I fail?**
> I could not figure out the regex to parse the selector

I believe in Google interview in 2017, the interviewer specifically told me *“we are not looking for regex experts, so don’t invest time there”*

In my case they were expecting me to break down the problem into simpler ones, I did this. I wrote seperate helper functions to do multiple things. And the unit functions which actually did finding part as **leveregeable** code, to be reused in all helpers **recursively**. The interviewer liked this and I cleared that round.

I will update the solution here in a week. In a gist, first you need to split the strings by spaces and `>` child selectors. For this splitting too, you can write a O(n) for-loop to go through the whole string. And not use the JS `.split` (not because it’s algorithm related, but because splitting that way will need further logic) For example, create child arrays only when you find one `>`.

Selectors on left has to be found. So I started with left first. I vaguely remember using t